# WPF: Multiple content presenters in a custom control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to have a custom control that requires 2 or more areas of the XAML to be defined by a child control - that inherits from this control. I'm wondering if there's a way to define multiple contentpresenters and one which acts as the default content presenter

```
<MyControl>
      <MyControl.MyContentPresenter2>
           <Button Content="I am inside the second content presenter!"/>
      </MyControl.MyContentPresenter2>

      <Button Content="I am inside default content presenter" />
</MyControl>
```

Is this possible, how do I define this in the custom control's template?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The template can just bind the separate `ContentPresenter` instances like this (I've only set one property here but you'll likely want to set others):

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content1}"/>
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content2}"/>
```

The control itself should expose two properties for content and set the default using the [`ContentPropertyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute.aspx):

```
[ContentProperty("Content1")]
public class MyControl : Control
{
    // dependency properties for Content1 and Content2
    // you might also want Content1Template, Content2Template, Content1TemplateSelector, Content2TemplateSelector
}
```

Comment: You can do this more directly by using the ContentSource attribute - this has the advantage of supporting templates and template selectors for the content also.

Comment: Kent, I don't need to set the ContentProperty attribute since it's already set to "Content". All I need is to set up another dependency property for "Content2" and bind that to another content presenter, but thanks for pointing me in the right dir

Comment: @foreyez: I was assuming you weren't inheriting from `ContentControl`. By the way, depending on your exact requirements, you might get away with just using a `HeaderedContentControl`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an "ItemsControl" with a custom template.

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Items[0]}"/>
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Items[1]}"/>
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Items[2]}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Style>
    <TextBlock Text="Item 1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Item 2"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Item 3"/>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option that doesn't require making a custom control and is more typesafe than doing the ItemsControl thing (if type safety is something you want..perhaps not):

...Use an attached property!

Create an attached property of the appropriate type. We happened to need a text control so I did a string TextContent attached property. Then create a TemplateBinding to it from the template, and when instantiating in Xaml set it there as well. Works nicely.