# How to bind nested components together Treeview,textbox & treeview?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I come from [How to use custom styles to bind with custom command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402551/how-to-use-custom-styles-to-bind-with-custom-command)
Here's my situation. I have a custom TabControl. And the ItemsSource is in a ViewModel.[Header and Content]. Now the Content is just simple strings.

```
public ViewModel()
    {
        TabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabData>();

        //dummy data
        TabItems.Add(new TabData() { Header = "Tab 1", Content = "Tab content 1" });
```

But I'd like to make the Content to be some other controls. To say a Grid with Textbox and Treeview inside. 
What's the ideal way to do this these kind of bindings?
I am thinking about create a userControl to hold the grid with textbox and treeview inside, and in the original ViewModel, I can write `Header = "Tab 1", Content = new UserControl()`

Comment: Ideal way is to use view models and datatemplates, instead of using the usercontrol itself as the content. I assume this question is a sequal of your previous question [how-to-use-custom-styles-to-bind-with-custom-command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402551/how-to-use-custom-styles-to-bind-with-custom-command), I'll answer your question based on the test project in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can implement view model for nested components

I'll demo the same by displaying a user control in Tab 2 via MVVM

so let's start by defining a view model class

```cs
public class Tab2ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Tab2ViewModel()
    {
        TabCommand = new SimpleCommand(OnTabCommand);
    }

    public ICommand TabCommand { get; private set; }

    private void OnTabCommand(object obj)
    {
        TabText = "Button was clicked";
    }

    private string _tabText;

    public string TabText
    {
        get { return _tabText; }
        set
        {
            _tabText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

`ViewModelBase` class in the code above is an implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` providing a method `RaisePropertyChanged` to notify the property changes

lets define a view for this view model

```
<UserControl x:Class="test_tab_control5.Views.Tab2View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Tab 1"
                   FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabText,FallbackValue=tab text}" Margin="10"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding TabCommand}"
                Content="Click me"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

now lets define a data template for the same

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Tab2ViewModel}">
    <vw:Tab2View />
</DataTemplate>
```

this is how you can define a template for the view models, in this case I a defining for `Tab2ViewModel`. in code above the namespaces defined as `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:test_tab_control5.ViewModels"` & `xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:test_tab_control5.Views"`

finally the usage

```cs
TabItems.Add(new TabData() { Header = "Tab 2", Content = new Tab2ViewModel() });
```

note that I am setting the content as `Tab2ViewModel` instead of any user control, this allows me implement a loose coupling between the view model and the view

and as a result WPF will resolve the user control as the template for the `Tab2ViewModel`

result

[image: result]

---

here is a full working sample for the above code: [MVVM TabControl.zip](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2f5wPS0jKJPeGFqRGVVbmlPZEE/view?pli=1)

MD5 Checksum: `4BA61028B5179AA884ECAC21D69A816A`

this sample is based on the sample shared in your previous question [How to use custom styles to bind with custom command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402551/how-to-use-custom-styles-to-bind-with-custom-command)

With the working sample I have also attempted to show couple of ways to define a template and usage of resource dictionaries

Comment: That's so illuminating!! In your example `<vm:MainViewModel/>` is defined in MainWindow. Could I say it will automatically look for its own DataTemplate, while the other  `Tab2ViewModel` inside `<vm:MainViewModel/>` will also looking for its DataTemplate

Comment: I tried to show you the few possible ways how to use data template to resolve the view for any view model. eg. for `vm:MainViewModel` it will load a tab control and for `Tab2ViewModel` it will resolve to a full user control. I also tried to show how you can separate different aspects of the code, so that the code don't get cluttered. last but not the least as long as a data template is defined and included in the resources wpf will automatically look up for the same, all you need to define the same for the correct data type. I hope this sample may help you explore more of wpf with mvvm.

Comment: Also do have a look on the `DataTemplates.xaml` in the Resource folder, this contains DataTemplates for the MainViewModel & Tab2ViewModel. you may define other data templates here. this file includes `Styles.xaml` which contains styles for the controls and it is added to `App.xaml`'s merged dictionary so it is available anywhere in the application.